# Arraylist get not filled

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I don't understand why the size is null. So the data is not loaded in the recyclerview.

I load the URLS from the Images from the my database and it should be shown into the recyclerview. I tested and I get the URL's but they are not added to the list.

```
SharedPreferences USERNAMEsp;
String USERNAME;

RecyclerView recyclerViewImageSlider;
List<ImageGetter> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
ImageGetter imageGetter;
PullData pullData = new PullData(Profil.this);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profil);

    USERNAMEsp = getSharedPreferences("DATAUSERNAME",MODE_PRIVATE);
    USERNAME = USERNAMEsp.getString("DATAUSERNAME","");

    pullData.getData(USERNAME, "3", new Pullcallback() {
        @Override
        public void getSingleData(String data) {
            imageGetter = new ImageGetter(data);
            imageList.add(imageGetter);
        }

        @Override
        public void getMultipleData(String[] multipledatas) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String errormessage) {

        }
    });

    recyclerViewImageSlider = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewImages);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(Profil.this, imageList, new AdapterCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLoaded() {

        }
    });
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Profil.this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    recyclerViewImageSlider.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerViewImageSlider.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewImageSlider.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    recyclerViewImageSlider.setOnFlingListener(new PagerSnapHelper());
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewImageSlider);

    imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: Not clear, please post full source code

Comment: What should be not clear? This is the sourcecode. I try to add the data into the list in the getSingleData

Comment: Where is your adapter implementation? After updating data source you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: pullData.getData() when this function wil be triggered?

Comment: @Raghunandan When I check the size inside getSingleData it shows that its added but not outside. I dont understand it, in my previous version it worked

Comment: @J.Doe as i mentioned earlier it is asynchronous while the data that you get can happen later you display toast immediately. Also what you do in adapter is not clear. Once you change the data set that populates adapter you need to call appropriate notify methods on adapter to inform that data set is changed

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged didn't changed anything. Added the adapter etc.

Comment: call `imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `imageList.add(imageGetter);`  because you are modifying arraylist and you have to let the `adapter` know to reload data set

Comment: Thanks Abu, that made it. Can't accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `imageList.add(imageGetter);` because you are modifying arraylist and you have to let the adapter know to reload data set

```
 pullData.getData(USERNAME, "3", new Pullcallback() {
    @Override
    public void getSingleData(String data) {
        imageGetter = new ImageGetter(data);
        imageList.add(imageGetter);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void getMultipleData(String[] multipledatas) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String errormessage) {

    }
});
```